# After moving from complete AWS setup to a standalone Wordpress Server, Media/Image Files are Broken

Tags: uploads, media-library

Linked images on old article is pointing to:

```
/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/filename.jpg
```

and isn't found.

Because the correct URL/Folder structure I got is:

```
/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/Some_Unique_ID/filename.jpg
```

I grab all these files from **AWS S3**.
Folder structure intact.

This **Some_Unique_ID** folder isn't present on new uploads.

Was this cause by Wordpress Update as I recall I updated it after moving to new server also.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay I got the reason why it's happening now, it's because of:
Offload S3 Lite Plugin > Object Versioning Feature > https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/doc/settings/#object-versioning

And we don't use that anymore now since we ditch AWS S3.

Comment: I already posted on the Plugin Support: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-revert-object-versioning-feature-feature-after-moving-out-from-aws-s3/ . I hope someone here already encounter this and have proper solution.

Comment: Eliminating this Some_Unique_ID folder will solve this problem:

/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/Some_Unique_ID/filename.jpg

Moving all files under /year/month/Some_Unique_ID/* back to /year/month/ folder.

I don't care leaving all those empty folder as long as it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the database:

```
mysqldump -u [db_username] --password=[db_password] "[db_name]" > "[db_name].sql"
```

Then you can use the tool of your choice to remove the unique ids:

```
sed -i -e 's/unique-id//g' [db_name].sql
```

Then import the resulting SQL file.

Comment: It's not the wordpress or database has the problem but the folder structures. By the way it's solved now.

Comment: Oh I’m sorry I thought you where referring to broken links in the content which IS IN THE DATABASE 